# brew doctor warnings - delete or ignore?

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

After I installed Homebrew,

Then I try the *brew doctor* command, there comes warnings:

[image]

[image]

Could I know the reasons and How to fix it? Could I just ignore these warnings?

Comment: This question is about Homebrew, not about Homebrew Cask. They used to be different packages, Homebrew Cask is part of Homebrew now but the question doesn't involve it. You should remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files reported by `brew doctor` are added by a software (that you manually installed before installing Homebrew) that uses a library for the [Tcl/Tk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl) language.

Homebrew also provides a library for Tcl/Tk and the existing files will conflict with those installed by Homebrew if you install a package that requires the Tcl/Tk library.

You don't have to worry for now and, very important, don't try to "fix" anything (especially don't remove files).

What you can do to "fix" it is to find out what program installed those files (it was not installed using the App Store, you installed it manually) and see if Homebrew provides it. If it is a macOS GUI application then Homebrew doesn't provide it (it contains only command line applications, no GUI) but Homebrew Cask might do it.

Use

```
$ brew search app
```

or

```
$ brew cask search app
```

If you are lucky and you find it and you are pleased with the version provided by Homebrew then you can uninstall the application using the uninstaller it hopefully provides then reinstall it using Homebrew (or Homebrew Cask).

You can run `brew doctor` between uninstall and reinstall to make sure the uninstaller removed all the files listed in the output of `brew doctor` now.

Comment: I am just afraid that there would be something wrong happening in the future. And I found that it is hard to deal with Tck/Tk files. Thank you man :)

Answer (score 1):

As written at the beginning of `brew doctor`'s output, you can safely ignore these warnings if everything you use Homebrew for works fine.